# How to post to blog module on Drupal 7 by PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, blogs

I have a problem with posting to Drupal 7 core blog module.

Can you give me a simple example (PHP code or MySQL query) how to add a blog post where:

```
Title="Blog post title"
Post content="Content".
```

I need a PHP or MySQL example. I don't want to post on home page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help pages first. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful. If you won't fix your question, you don't get any answer most probably.

Answer (score 1):

create it programatically by writing this code in your module file

```html
 $text_body = 'Your node body text';
$node = new stdClass();  // Create a new node object
$node->type = 'blog';  // Content type
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;  // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
node_object_prepare($node);  //Set some default values
 
$node->title = 'Your node title';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $text_body;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($text_body);
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
 
$node->status = 1;   // (1 or 0): published or unpublished
$node->promote = 0;  // (1 or 0): promoted to front page or not
$node->sticky = 0;  // (1 or 0): sticky at top of lists or not
$node->comment = 1;  // 2 = comments open, 1 = comments closed, 0 = comments hidden
// Add author of the node
$node->uid = 1;
// Set created date
$node->date = 'complaint_post_date';
$node->created = strtotime('complaint_post_date');
 
$path = 'content/blog-' . date('YmdHis');
$node->path = array('alias' => $path);
// Save the node
node_save($node);
```